Is there an extension for visual studio code that visualizes the command line of gdb-multiarch in a gui?
So i'm using gdbserver and gdb-multiarch to access the software in a container and to debug it remotely on visual studio code.
To make this easier to use for people that have no experience with the command line, i would love to have a graphical user interface.
Is there any extension for VSC that visualizes what you would otherwise have to type out in the command line?
I hope the question is clear, i'm happy with any kind of help and will try to answer followup questions.
I found some references that might be what i'm searching for but not as extension for VSC.
KDbg was something i found right away that sounded good.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
